# Add multiple items from a firebase tree and display on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is a picture of the firebase database tree . I have items a, b , c. I want the value of totalresult = a + b + c

**My requirement is** : As the value of a or b or c gets updated , it should get automatically reflected in the totalresult item value.

Is there a way to set in firebase to do it automatically instead running a piece of code everytime to add these and update in firebase

[image]

Am able to run a piece of code to add these and update the value in totalresult. But I have to run it manually every time, which is not an ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an internal way to do this in firebase realtime database.

That said, while you still have to write code, you can write a firebase function to trigger on updates to those fields, and then apply the update to total result.  This will be automatic instead of manual, as the trigger will happen for every event on the database.

Documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for how to create such a trigger (probably using the "onWrite" event).

Of course, there are a few things to be aware of:

- There will be a period of time while the function is running that the data is not updated.  In other words, you should be tolerant of inconsistencies.  (You will likely also want to do the actual writing to the total using a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions))
- You need to be careful to not run the function (or exit early) when "tot/total result" is being updated, or you could get into an infinite loop of functions (it'd be best to have the result object elsewhere in your tree)